# Search and replace in an array

Tags: regex, perl, replace

Say I have an array which has the below data

```
@array = ('/root/level1','/root/level2',
          '/root/level1/level2','/root/level1/level2/level3')
```

I want to loop over this array and replace each element with its last word as

```
@array = ('level1','level2','level2','level3')
```

I am not good with regex, can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using split and map:

```
@array=map{(split(/\//,$_))[-1]}@array;
```

Using regex:

```
@array=map{m|.*/(.*)|}@array;
```

Answer (score 3):

Why use regex when you have the [`File::Basename`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aBasename) module to do the work for you. It is a core module in Perl 5.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Basename;

my @array = ('/root/level1',
             '/root/level2',
             '/root/level1/level2',
             '/root/level1/level2/level3');

@array = map basename($_), @array;
print Dumper \@array;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'level1',
          'level2',
          'level2',
          'level3'
        ];
```

Comment: Actually the array which I have doesn't contain file paths, these are simple names which looks like paths but they aren't. So I'll prefer to use regex.

Comment: Do you think regexes use different rules than this module does?